# Can i define a parameter within a method for use in a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, parameters

I'm trying to think of a very clean way to do this and while I find I could have endless if statements to do it, this seems easiest, but I'm stuck as to how to make it work.

```java
public StringBuilder applianceReturn(String app1, String, app2, String app3){
    StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
        String appliance = "app" + i;
        if (appliance != null){
            finalString.append(appliance);
        }
        else finalString.append("nothing");
            break;
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), finalString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return finalString;
}
```

Of course my issue is that the method doesn't recognize "app" + i as a parameter.  Is there anyway to make this work so its not going to be if (app1 != null)... if (app2 !=null) etc..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you try to achieve here. You can define a varargs parameter `String... app` where app becomes a String array you can loop over.

Comment: Pass an array of strings instead of three separate arguments?  Pretty much any time you have variable names with incrementing numbers like that, what you want is an array/list/etc.

Comment: 3 if statements are not endless, they are 3. if you have a dynamic or high number of parameters you should accept a list, array or varargs.

Comment: Are you aware that this `break;` will end your for loop each time i == 1 ?

Comment: So to clarify, app1 would return a string of 1 or null depending of if a box is checked or not in an android application.  Each app# is a different check box defining a variable.  I kept this at 3 for the sake of the example, there are many more check boxes. The point to it create a final string that is used in a SQL query based upon boxes that are either checked or not.

Comment: Exactly what marcinj said. Your `else` branch lacks braces, so now you are confusing yourself with the `break` statement, which is unconditionally executed with the first iteration of your `for` loop, rendering the loop useless.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do can be achieved with a varargs argument and an enhanced for loop.  The result might look something like this.

```
public StringBuilder applianceReturn(String... apps){
    StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder();
    for (String eachApp : apps){
        finalString.append(eachApp);
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), finalString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return finalString;
}
```

This will allow you to pass any number of `String` arguments into the method, and arrange them into an array.  You can then iterate through this array, doing whatever you like to the arguments.